# A question about common mode noise

Tags: noise, common-mode

This is a conceptual question. Imagine I have the end of a signal chain at a BNC connector and when I hook it up to a scope I observe noise. Signal chain and everything is single-ended. Imagine a DC signal is the actual signal from a single-ended temperature transducer and there is significant noise observed on it.

1-) How can I check quickly and verify whether the noise is common mode or not? I was thinking to use a LP filter to verify it. For example if there is 1kHz noise and 10Hz filter does not filter it I would say it is common mode noise. But Im not sure if this is a method or correct.

2-) If the noise is 50Hz and its harmonics is it big possibility that the noise is common mode noise? if it is common mode noise can it be filter by a passive or active filter? Or a choke should be used?

Comment: In order for something to even acquire the "common mode" property you need two inputs working in a differential manner, if I'm not mistaken. Which you are not doing if I can read your text correctly.

Comment: Not ideal but you can get a good clue if noise is common mode by adding a common mode filter in your test lead. The simplest way of achieving this is to get a clip on ferrite if the noise reduces when you clip it around your scope lead then some of it is common mode.  You get even better performance with two (or more) turns around your ferrite.

Comment: @WarrenHill not really... When you clip a ferrite round two wires you cause the noise to balance between them. You are making it common noise. As such it seems to be less on the scope. You have not technically made the noise go away, you just cant see it from one wire to the other. It's like two boats sitting next to each other orthogonal to the waves. They both go up an down at the same time so there is no relative wave motion between them.

Comment: @Trevor I need to think about this, It does not fit with my understanding. I'll either post an apology to this comment or a new question so you can reply in further detail. If my conceptions are wrong I am happy to learn but I do need convincing here.

Comment: @WarrenHill its a fairly simple mechanism. A spike in one line creates a spike in the magnetic field in the ferrite that induces a spike in the other. Basically a transformer. Energy is transferred so spike lowers in first line. But sum remains the same... well there are always losses... but maybe you get the picture.

Comment: @Trevor I have posted a new question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/336325/26566) If you want to post a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @WarrenHill I think we are talking about different things here.. A choke will tend to dissipate energy that is already common noise. I'm talking about noise in a cable that is not common, like in COAX. In this case the choke actually cross couples the noise.

Comment: @WarrenHill A common mode choke that is

Answer (score 1):

BNC (with coax cable) and Common Mode do not go in the same sentence.

Common mode noise is talking about a signal current being passed round a pair of wires, be that as a differential signal or as a single ended signal with a reference line. Both lines need to be subject to similar electromagnetic fields for the noise to be common to each.

BNC, with coax, is a single signal wire shielded by the return reference. As such the signal does not receive the same noise as the shield. So common mode noise can not really be applied to BNC cables.

If you want to pass a signal some distance and have the common mode noise removed, make the signal differential and pass it through a twisted pair cable which may or may not be shielded. Alternatively, pass a single ended signal with it's reference through a similar twisted pair cable and use the reference in your receiver.

Comment: Would a coaxial cable help newage2000?

Comment: @HarrySvensson BNC IS coax, well it's really a connector standard, but it's meant to be used with coax. I suppose I did assume he was using the BNC as intended.

Comment: Trevor I feel I may be being a bit too pedantic here but I have a scope with a battery pack, not strictly true I think it is actually just a really big capacitor, If I unplug my scope from the mains the measured noise sometimes goes down. doesn't this suggest that at least some of this is due to a difference between my (earthed) return probe and mains earth? This would suggest to me a ground loop current and so common mode noise. Please correct me if you have an alternative explanation.

Comment: @WarrenHill I cant really comment on that. It depends on how the grounds are hooked up in the scope. It could make it better, it could make it worse.